# I always need to press F1 to go to bios whenever I turning on my computer, how to fix it?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I always got this whenever I turn my computer on:
[image: Link to image]

I know this happen when there's an error or something wrong with the hardware, but I don't know which problem it is referring.

**Symptoms**

- This occurred when I plugged off the computer from it's power source,
  even though it is properly shutdown.

**My Current Fix**

- Not actually a fix, but to use my computer I just press `F1` to go in
  bios and press `F10` then hit `Enter` just to quickly save the
  current settings and reboot. After the reboot no problem is shown
  anymore.

**Possible Cause**

- It could be the CMOS Battery is already failing, but I have a doubt
  about it because I bought the motherboard 1 year ago, I
  think it's not that old to cause this problem, I also don't have a new
  cmos battery to try it and it will took 3days to order online because
  there's no nearest store in my current location.

What do you think guys? What is the solution for this problem? Anyway, the model of motherboard is `Asus B75m-a`.

Comment: I had the same problem back then, my motherboard is 2 years old, same manufacture. I couldn't find any solution from the internet so what I did is change the `cmos battery` to a new one then disable the option in the bios saying `wait for the F1 error` something like that, then I din't get the error anymore. The only problem is that I disabled the option `Wait for F1 error` meaning I didn't fix the problem and I just ignore it. I don't know if I fix it by changing the cmos battery to a new one, it's gone anyway. Hope someone can help you.

Comment: If you change some bios settings, then turn off the computer & check the settings later, are they reset or still changed?

Comment: Even tho you just purchased the motherboard 1 year ago the copyright date on the bios is 2012, suggesting your motherboard may have been sitting “on the shelf” somewhere for an extended period.  Given that I suspect the CMOS battery too.

Comment: CMOS battery. That’s the most obvious thing. Simple and cheap to try.

Comment: If changing the CMOS battery does not help, you might reflash the BIOS to your motherboard's latest version. Take backups first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BIOS is misbehaving or forgetting settings, there are only two procedures
I can think of that you might do yourself :

- Replacing the CMOS battery.
- Reflash the BIOS to your motherboard's latest version.

Ensure that you have good backups of your computer before starting.

If the above does not solve the problem, then a repair-shop is the next stop,
as the problem cannot be solved by simple manipulations.

Comment: it does fixed by replacing new cmos battery

Comment: it's just strange that the settings in bios are saving and not resetting into it's defaults...